# Implication of Correlation on Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

I came across a result saying that if the conditional expectation function $E[Y|X=x]$ is increasing in $x$, then the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ must be positive. Is there any kind of converse to this? That is, if the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is positive, can we say anything about $E[Y|X\geq x]$ and $E[Y|X\leq x]$?

Answer (score 0):

If $E[Y|X]=h(X)$, with $h$ an increasing function, then $Y$ is positively  correlated with every random variable of the form $g(X)$, with $g$ increasing (provided the correlations exist). This more detailed correlation information as hypothesis may lead to an interesting converse. The positive correlation of $Y$ and $X$ alone seems to be not enough information to get what you want.